# Why is the returned height of sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode: always the same?

Tags: iphone

For some reason, the CGSize which is returned by sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode: is pretty useless. In my case it remains 55 no matter how much the text gets shrinked. It's always the same value. It never changes. The only thing that seems to work is the actualFontSize but that doesn't tell me a lot about how heigh the text rectangle is now, does it? (don't know much about typography but I think this pica font size stuff sucks and never works really precise)

Comment: can you supply the code you are using.... it would b a great help in determining your problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem with sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode: so came up with a solution for calculating the height based on the actualFontSize.

It is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13517335/1791042