# Always getting the same height using sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, nsstring

The CGSize returned by sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode: contains always the same height. Why is that, and is there a way around this?

I want to align a string vertically and it may not be truncated, unless it can't fit on a single line using the minimum font size. So I try to use this method to get the line height but it always returns 57px no matter what the actualFontSize is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you report what you're passing for the other arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding the `actualFontSize` parameter. This is an out parameter only, not an in parameter. It does not matter what value you provide for `actualFontSize`; if the pointer is non-NULL, then it will be overwritten with the font size used in determining the returned size. The returned actual font size will be between the `minFontSize:` and the size of the `UIFont` instance provided as the argument to the `sizeWithFont:` portion of the selector.

You also must be sure to send this message to the string you intend to render. You would always get the same value, for example, if you are asking a dummy string that's less than a line long how much height it would take for the supplied width.

If you update your question with the actual code used in calling the method, everyone would be better able to help you.

Comment: Regardless of the proper use of actualFontSize. The CGSize returned by this method does not calculate the correct height.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have the `actualFontSize` from `sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`

Then you can calculate the height required to render using:

```
CGFloat actualHeight = [font fontWithSize:actualFontSize].ascender-[font fontWithSize:actualFontSize].descender;
```

(I found [this](http://www.hackberry-fonts.com/type_terms.html) page useful in understanding the various size values relating to fonts.)