# sizewithfont:forwidth:linebreakmode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

Why doesn't this work? It always returns 18 no matter the length of the string. There is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640558/always-getting-the-same-height-using-sizewithfontminfontsizeactualfontsizefor), but not a definitive answer.

```
    NSString * t = @"<insert super super long string here>";

    CGSize size = [t sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0] forWidth:285 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    NSLog(@"size.height is %f and text is %@", size.height, t);
```

Thanks,

Todd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` instead.

```
NSString * t = @"<insert super super long string here>";
CGSize constrainSize = CGSizeMake(285, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize size = [t sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0] constrainedToSize:constrainSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
NSLog(@"size.height is %f and text is %@", size.height, t);
```

Comment: Aha, I knew there was a different one to call but couldn't remember, +1

Comment: Perfect, it works, many thanks! I don't understand why the other call does not work, I am going to go over the documentation a few more times.

Answer (score 1):

**DEPRECATED Method: NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0)**

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:");
```

Example

```
CGSize titleTextSize = [self.titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.myLabel.font forWidth:myLabelWidth lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
```

**New Approach**

Use :

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size
                       options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options
                    attributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *,
                                        id> *)attributes
                       context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context
```

Example:

```
 // Create a paragraph style with the desired line break mode
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;

    // Create the attributes dictionary with the font and paragraph style
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 NSFontAttributeName:self.myLabel.font,
                                 NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle
                                 };

    // Call boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context for the string
    CGRect textRect = [self.countLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthOfMyLabel, 999999.0f)
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                        attributes:attributes
                                           context:nil];
```

[See Appple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize size = [t sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:16.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220,500) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```